# Is there a way to rename Hyperledger Fabric Composer command from 'composer' to something else?

Tags: php, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

After installing Hyperledger Fabric Composer I have had to create an alias for PHP Composer 'composer' command as running the command executes Hyperledger Composer instead due to name conflict.  Is there a way to rename the Hyperledger Fabric Composer command rather than doing this for PHP Composer as the PHP Composer gets executes automatically when installing a number of frameworks etc. and obviously this results in an error.  It would seem to me to make more sense to rename / alias Hyperledger Composer as this is almost always manually executed.  Any ideas over my current approach very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I have managed to solve the issue in a few steps.  I like Dan's fcomposer name above so I will use that.

1. Move the symlink for Hyperledger Composer (you can find out where it is located by running `which composer` at the prompt.
2. Create an alias (in .bash_aliases) for fcmposer and point to the new symlink name
3. Make sure your composer alias in .bashrc / .bash_aliases is linked to PHP composer

Going to +1 Dan's answer because it put me on the right path.  Thanks Dan!

Comment: I have the reverse problem, executing _composer_ runs the PHP Composer, but I need to run the Hyperledger's. This causes the downloaded sample Fabric scripts throw lots of errors.  I added 2 aliases in %userprofile%/.bashrc: `alias composer=/c/Users/<user>/AppData/Roaming/npm/composer
alias pcomposer=/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer`

Comment: But I still get error "Cannot use Composer version 1.5.2 2017-09-11 16:59:25 version of composer with fabric 1.2, v0.20 or higher is required". Any idea?

Comment: where do you move the symlink for Hyperledger Composer in step 1?

Comment: Same location, just renamed it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can add an alias in your `~/.bashrc` . For example to rename it fcomposer:

`alias fcomposer=/usr/bin/composer`

Or you can simply have a softlink from a directory in your path.  For example,

`ln -s /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/fcomposer`